# Wrong value default ENUM Mysql type

Tags: php, mysql, database, enums

as i see every where even in here :

> From the MySQL manual:
>
> If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a
>   legal value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an ENUM
>   column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of
>   the list of permitted values.

But in my database is not like this !!!! Why ?

this is one of field structure :

```
`dead` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

but why all data in the dead field is null ???

and if i chose that type to enter a value this will be list :

```
 ()Empty
 (0)
 (1)
```

Why always null is there ?

and another thing is when i use query like this :

```
 UPDATE TABLE SET dead = 0 -> result : dead = null
 UPDATE TABLE SET dead = 1 -> result : dead = 0
 UPDATE TABLE SET dead = 2 -> result : dead = 1
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Sounds to me like you "think" you declared it null, but your modify to do so failed. Try again to "alter yourtable modify dead enum('0','1') not null default '0' "

Comment: @avk ALTER TABLE test CHANGE `dead` `dead` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL;       still not working and null is there too and act like first element

Comment: Can you show the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE test`?

Comment: ALTER TABLE test MODIFY dead ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'. Not: ALTER TABLE test CHANGE dead dead ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL

Comment: @infomaniac     CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `heroid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `dead` enum('1','2') NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`heroid`),
 KEY `uid` (`uid`),
 KEY `dead` (`dead`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Your table has no default value for the `dead` column?

Comment: @infomaniac There is No different in result if it has or not i dont know why

Comment: MySQL does some weird things with default values and `NULL`s when you change columns and there is already data in the table.
`TRUNCATE TABLE test` and add your default value to your column, and then try.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are asking for.

Here is fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b24d0/1

As we can see when `dead` is not set in `INSERT` query:

```
insert into table1 (id) values (4);
```

mysql put there your default value `'0'` and that is what you were expecting I guess.

I don't know what version of mysql do you use, but in my fiddle it is clear that mysql doesn't allow to:

```
UPDATE  table1 SET dead = 0;
```

Since it is enum, it only allows:

```
UPDATE  table1 SET dead = '0';
```

And that is correct and expected behavior since you choose `ENUM` type for the column. So I can't reproduce described in OP behavior. If anybody else can?

**GUESS** I guess that you are trying to convert existing table column with existing data in that column and stuck. So to run alter table you should fix data first like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET dead='0' WHERE dead IS NULL;
```

So once you get data fixed you can try `ALTER TABLE`  to set `DEFAULT`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. yes in the fiddle is just fine but not in the mysql . my mysql ver is :                                                                                               Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) . when i set query : UPDATE  table1 SET dead = '' WHERE id = 1; it will set `dead` to null value

Comment: as i search a lot i see this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html it says => the index value of the empty string error value is 0.But one of my option is 0 ! how can i do that ? is another data type like ENUM can i use to select only available field value ?

Comment: try to uncomment your query `UPDATE table1 SET dead = '' WHERE id = 1;` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/877f3/1  it doesn't bring null value. it brings an error

Comment: yes BUT ! if you use SQL STRICT mode ( if i right it correctly . sry )

Comment: show me the proof please. Because just in common sense **strict** means less freedom and more following some rules. So if non-strict mode not allows to do something, how can be strict mode less strict to the rules?

Comment: If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid ENUM values result in an error. in here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html